# How to create a cookie with a variable value

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I need to create a javascript cookie in order to do something with PHP (to be exactly, I need to get the viewport height of the browser, store that in a javascript cookie in order to get the value inside PHP). The only problem is I have no javascript experience, and I dont't understand google's explanation.

I'd like to have this value (`var viewportHeight = $(window).height();`) inside a cookie. 
But how?

(google only gives examples with a static value).

Comment: Are you using the jQuery Cookie plugin?

Comment: Er... I think that if you need help with some code, you should *post* that code here.

Answer (score 2):

try something like this:

```
var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
document.cookie = "viewportheight=" + viewportHeight + ";";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have dynamic values for a cookie. You can however update the cookie every time the window resizes:

```
$(function(){
   $(window).resize(function () { 
      createCookie( 'viewportHeight', $(window).height() );
   });
});

// You should also use some cross-browser cookie functions that make your life a lot easier
// function taken from: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```

This way you can simulate "dinamic" values for a cookie.
Alternatively, you can just send the value via ajax to a php script every time the browser resizes, without having to use cookies at all

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a bad idea to me. Your layout shouldn't required the exact pixel dimensions on the server side. But, if you really have no other option:

Use this jQuery plugin: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Then you can do the following:

```
// save the window height to a cookie whenever window is resized
$(window).resize(function(){
    $.cookie('viewportHeight', $(window).height(), {path:'/'});
});

// trigger the resize function so it saves the cookie on first load
$(window).load(function(){        
    window.setTimeout(function() {$(window).resize();}, 0);
}
```

Then you access it from PHP in subsequent requests like so:

```
$viewportHeight = $_COOKIE['viewportHeight'];
```

Please note that if you need the cookie value in PHP before the user sees the first page, this will not work.

Comment: Is that it? And include the plugin? When i echo $viewportHeight afterwards I get Undefined index: viewportHeight in /gallery.php on line 26. (Just used your code)

Comment: Make sure you echo $viewportHeight after at least one page view. Only after the first view will the cookie exist and be sent to subsequent requests.
Also, I updated the script: added a path to make it site-wide + call resize on first load... try it now.